# How to display a clickable pie chart in the cell of a html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to create a web page which displays some quick info in a table. I want to display this info as a pie chart. Is it possible? I am planning on using HighCharts for charting. As this project is in the planning stage, I need to be sure of everything I propose before the plan is final.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks in advance
Pallavi

Comment: HighCharts, is in my opinion, the best JS visualization package available. Great support from the community and great documentation!

Comment: look at `D3 charts` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Using a table is not restricting you from displaying whatever you want. Furthermore setting up a demo for this should not take you more than an hour, so I suggest you do it :) This way you will be sure that things can be done. This is a piece of advice not just for this project but in general.

Check out the [Highchart api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click) for more information.

Comment: I'll check it out

Answer (score 2):

Ye with HighCharts its possible. They have nice website with a lot of good simple [documents](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) and examples

Comment: I'll have a look at the documents

Answer (score 2):

If you're using it for non-commercial purpose then can use high-charts - [PieChart using Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/) 
else you can use d3.js for accomplishing the same - [PieChart using D3.js](https://jsfiddle.net/ragingsquirrel3/qkHK6/)

```
var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
              {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
              {"label":"Category C", "value":30}];
            ...........................
```

Note: refer the rest of the code from the fiddle link above.

Comment: It is for non-commercial purposes which is why I settled for Highcharts. But does d3.js provide for more flexibility than highcharts?

Comment: Yes,d3.js provides more flexibility and if you have to do more complex data manipulation then it is good to go, on the other hand if want simple charts then go for highcharts.

Comment: Ok. Will check out d3.js